# Array isn't being populated. List view isn't populating either. Array size more than one but only one value printing

Tags: android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

After getting my json response from the GET method I put it into an array but after only one value is shown but it says the size is larger than one.
Listview isn't populating either. The custom adapters were used exactly as such before too but it's not working now.

This is full file which isn't working currently. The output i am expecting is: the list view to be populated with the `holderArray.getF2FName()`. It doesn't work even after rebuilding the project.

Code starts here:

```
public class rSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
ListView listView;
RequestQueue rQueue;
ArrayList<F2FHolder> holderArray = new ArrayList<F2FHolder>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_r_search);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.rSearchList);
    itemList = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("passingArray");

    for(int i=0;i<itemList.size();i++){
        System.out.println(itemList.get(i));
    }

    rQueue = VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).getmRequestQueue();

    parse(new CallBack() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ArrayList<F2FHolder> holderArray) {
            if(holderArray.size()>0){
                f2fAdapter adapter = new f2fAdapter();
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(rSearchActivity.this,"No recipes available containing these ingredients, try different\n" +
                        "ingredients",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFail(String msg) {
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
    });

}

public void parse(final CallBack onCallBack){
    String url =""; //url

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            F2FHolder adder = new F2FHolder();
            try {
                int count = response.getInt("count");
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("recipes");
                for(int i=0; i<count;i++){
                    JSONObject f2f = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String FName = f2f.getString("title");
                    String link = f2f.getString("f2f_url");
                    adder.setF2FName(FName);
                    adder.setUrl(link);
                    holderArray.add(adder);

                }
                onCallBack.onSuccess(holderArray);



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                onCallBack.onFail(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    rQueue.add(request);


}


class f2fAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return holderArray.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.edittextview,null);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editTextBox);
        textView.setText(holderArray.get(position).getF2FName());

        return convertView;
    }
}

public interface CallBack {
    void onSuccess(ArrayList<F2FHolder> holderArray);

    void onFail(String msg);
}
```

}

Comment: Have you followed what is going on in a debugger?  That's how I find logic problems like thtis.

Comment: @Steve yes then it shows all list items with the same value. It really doesnt make sense